# Ros jade on Mac OS X El Capitan

Tags: homebrew, uuid, osx-elcapitan, ros

I am trying to install ROS Jade on Mac OS X El Capita. I am following this instructions set for Homebrew.

I am able to initialize the ROS package but when I try to install the ROS package using the command

```
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro jade
```

i get the following error message

```
executing command [brew install uuid]
==> Installing uuid from ros/deps
==> Downloading http://gnome-build-stage-1.googlecode.com/files/uuid-1.6.2.tar.gz

curl: (52) Empty reply from server
Error: Failed to download resource "uuid"
Download failed: http://gnome-build-stage-1.googlecode.com/files/uuid-1.6.2.tar.gz
ERROR: the following rosdeps failed to install
homebrew: command [brew install uuid] failed
```

If anyone has run into this error please let me know a way to install uuid on mac
or any other way of installing ROS on mac os x.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure homebrew is installed correctly? Try http://www.howtogeek.com/211541/homebrew-for-os-x-easily-installs-desktop-apps-and-terminal-utilities/

Comment: Just running `brew install uuid` should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, but after running the command

```
$ rosdep init
```

something changed. Now I am stacked on the package libogre-dev, that is missing. I hope it could be helpful.